# Android: Two instances of Media recorder at same time

Tags: android, multithreading, record, mediarecorder

Can i run two instances of Android MediaRecorder class at the same time? For example

```
public MediaRecorder mrec1 ;
public MediaRecorder mrec2 ;


mrec1.setCamera(mCamera);
mrec1.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder.getSurface());
mrec1.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA)
.
.
.
.
mrec2.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
mrec2.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
mrec2.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
.
.  
.
.
mrec1.prepare();
mrec2.prepare();
mrec1.start();
mrec2.start();
```

I get this error when second start() is called i just want to know is it because there is already a start process called or there is some other problem. Also the second media recorder instance is initialized and used in a separate thread.

```
04-22 11:08:45.869: E/MediaRecorder(7742): start failed: -2147483648
04-22 11:08:45.869: W/dalvikvm(7742): threadid=9: thread exiting with uncaught exception  (group=0x40018578)
04-22 11:08:45.869: E/AndroidRuntime(7742): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-10
04-22 11:08:45.869: E/AndroidRuntime(7742): java.lang.RuntimeException: start failed.
```

Answer (score 2):

according to [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html#release()):

> In addition to unnecessary resources (such as memory and instances of
>   codecs) being held, failure to call this method immediately if a
>   MediaRecorder object is no longer needed may also lead to continuous
>   battery consumption for mobile devices, **and recording failure for
>   other applications** if no multiple instances of the same codec are
>   supported on a device. Even if multiple instances of the same codec
>   are supported, some performance degradation may be expected when
>   unnecessary multiple instances are used at the same time.

My unsuccessful attempts led to nothing either.

Comment: Can we detect this in any way that some particular device supports "multiple instances of the same codec"